# How can I disable animations in Firefox when going full screen?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

I would like to disable the transition animation when I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to go full screen on Firefox.

The animation slowly pulls up all the tabs and bars off the screen instead of immediately hiding everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the newest versions of Firefox:

1. Open the `about:config` website
2. Set `toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled` to `false`

Tested on:

- Firefox 57.0b9 (32-bit) from the Debian experimental branch running on Debian testing (*buster*)
- Firefox 56.0 (64-bit) running on Ubuntu 17.10
- Firefox 68.0 (64-bit) running on FreeBSD 13.0-CURRENT

---

#### References

- [*about:config browser.fullscreen.animateUp has no effect*  (support.mozilla.org)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1173145)
- All the other the resources I found on the Internet were outdated (they suggest modifying options in about:config, which no longer exist).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Firefox 77.0.

Comment: This is no longer the answer for the "newest versions of Firefox".

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 83.0:

1. Open the `about:config`
2. Change `full-screen-api.transition-duration.enter` from `200 200` to `0 0`.
3. Change `full-screen-api.transition-duration.leave` from `200 200` to `0 0`.

Comment: Hmmm, I've got all those set to zeros, but it still does not disable the animations for me on Firefox 83.0.

Comment: This disables the fade-to-black *transition* that happens when going fullscreen with the Fullscreen API, but has no effect on the UI element animation that the question is referring to.

Comment: This problem and solution are described in more detail in [another question](https://superuser.com/a/1742261/133421).