# How to disable Firefox address bar animation on fullscreen?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, address-bar, firefox-77

How can I disable the address bar hiding animation when going fullscreen in Firefox?

I'm trying to accomplish what [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1265807/how-can-i-disable-animations-in-firefox-when-going-full-screen) is about. The solution was to set `toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled` to `false` in `about:config`, but this is not working anymore - the animation returned once I updated to 77 and is still a problem in 78.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: make sure you set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true`  in your `about:config` [page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) before attempting to use custom stylesheets!

You can add the following in your userchrome.css. Learn how to create or edit one here https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html

```css
/* To completely disable fullscreen transition */

#navigator-toolbox[fullscreenShouldAnimate] {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

```css
/* To drastically reduce transition time - zero doesn't work, minimum is 0.01 */

#navigator-toolbox[fullscreenShouldAnimate] {
  transition: .15s !important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything. I tried both `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css`, but no luck. Thank you for the answer, though!

Comment: It works fine for me, fwiw here are my settings for my firefox, customizations for URL Bar etc, the animation code is at the end. https://gist.github.com/wapenshaw/b70afc7590c88d387a81d989041c111d

Are you sure your userchrome.css is being loaded?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/htf6uxH.gifv Here is a recording of how it works with settings file i  linked https://i.imgur.com/htf6uxH.gifv

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of response, and I appreaciate your answer and comments! I'm not sure why I've never encountered the need for it before, but per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Tutorial/Modifying_the_Default_Skin) I was required to enable `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`, and now your solution works!
I hope that Mozilla will not kill off the option of personal CSS, but for now your solution works and will be accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Ohh damn, i forgot they disabled legacy stylesheets! that flag was set on my setup since they disabled user css the first time! sorry I missed it!