# How can I disable the fade to black animation when going fullscreen on a video in firefox?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

When setting a video to fullscreen, it does this annoying fade-to-black animation.

I am posting this as finding an up-to-date solution was quite difficult, so I figured I'd share it to make it easier for others to find.

This is working as of Firefox version: 104.0.2

Edit: Someone has identified this as a duplicate of [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1265807/how-can-i-disable-animations-in-firefox-when-going-full-screen).

While that question does feature the answer to my question, the questions are about two different animations with different solutions.

Their question is about the animation for setting the browser to fullscreen using `f11` which is a different animation and is not removed in the same manner.

So while the answer to this question is submitted on that question it has terrible discoverability due to being posted as the answer to a different question.

Comment: The version that the solution applies to should go in the answer along with the solution rather than in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable animations in Firefox when going full screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1265807/how-can-i-disable-animations-in-firefox-when-going-full-screen)

Comment: @music2myear While it does contain the answer to my question, the answer does not answer the question it was submitted to so it should remain here as a complete question+answer pair for discoverability.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To disable the animation (or change the animation speed), go to the URL `about:config`.

Search for `full-screen-api.transition-duration.enter` and `full-screen-api.transition-duration.leave` and change both to `0 0` to disable the animation completely.

Edit: Someone mentioned I should post the version in the answer and not just the question.

This is working as of Firefox version: 104.0.2

Comment: The default value for those seems to be `0 0`, so it seems like if you have a delay then you would have had to have changed it yourself already, unless some add-on did it?

Comment: @Herohtar The default is actually `200 200`. If your copy of Firefox was already set to `0 0` (and you're sure you didn't do it yourself), then an extension you've installed or some customization has already changed it for you.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield It doesn't show up as a modified value, and if I set it to `200 200` (or anything else) then it shows up as modified, after which, pressing "Reset" will set it back to `0 0`. I haven't installed any extensions or made any modifications that would affect it. It looks like `200 200` might have been the default value at one time, but that does not appear to be the case any more.

Comment: @Herohtar Interesting, because I just installed Firefox on a Windows 10 PC last week, and the default was `200 200`.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield Actually, [looking at the source](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/0948667bc62415d48abff27e1405fb4ab4d65d75/modules/libpref/init/all.js#3635-3641) it appears that the default value depends on what flag it is built with. It looks like builds that use GTK (eg, for Linux) have it set to `0 0`. And understandably, because there's kind of an ugly flash during the transition if you do enable it there.

Comment: @Herohtar Now that's just weird...

Comment:  Still works for Firefox 116.0.3 on Windows 11.